# Ubuntu 14.04 turns off abruptly instead of suspend when battery low

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, low-power

My Ubuntu 14.04 laptop turns off abruptly without showing any warning or notification even though I have set it to suspend when battery low what is the underlying problem?

Comment: Is the battery good? It could be that the battery is bad and reporting wrong data. If the battery is reporting 15%, but it's already damaged, it in reality will hold less data thus turning itself off.

Comment: I have to get my battery checked. I will then post a comment here.